# Python breaking from a while loop + exceptions

Tags: python

I have the following python code, which is designed to run a fortran code called `cctfiles`.  Then I take a snapshot of the running processes by me `abedin` and write the snapshot to a file called `sample.txt`. Then I read the file `sample.txt` until the running process `./cctfiles` is gone from the file. But I noticed that even though the program `cctfiles` has exited, my python code won't break from the while loop.
So here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import subprocess

scb = subprocess.call



def runprog(name):
        for i in xrange(1,2):
                scb('cp '+name+' '+str(i), shell = 'True')
                scb('sleep 1', shell = 'True')
                scb('(cd '+str(i)+';'+' ./'+name+' &)', shell = 'True')
                print('Job '+str(i)+' has been sent:')
#               scb('cd ../', shell = 'True')

        while True:
                scb('sleep 5', shell = 'True')
                scb('ps -ef | grep abedin > sample.txt', shell = 'True')
                cnt = subprocess.Popen('grep -c ".*" sample.txt',stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell = 'True')
                (c,err) = cnt.communicate()
                nlines = int(c.strip())
                fl = open('sample.txt', 'r+')
                count = 0
                class BreakIt(Exception): pass
                try:
                        for line in fl:
                                count = count + 1
                                for word in line.strip().split():
#                                       print(word.strip())
                                        if word.strip() != './'+name and count == nlines:
                                                raise BreakIt
                except BreakIt:
                        pass

                else: break

            fl.seek(0)
            fl.truncate()
            fl.close()
    print('----------Finaly Done------------')


runprog('cctfiles')
```

Any help will be highly appreciated, given my poor knowledge of Python!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: At a first glance, it looks like when you catch a `BreakIt` exception, you should actually `break it` (https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#break) **:-)** Also, you have a kind of `BreakIt` built-in: https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.StopIteration

Comment: If you want to check, if a program is still running, you should use subprocesses `poll`.

Comment: I'd recommend you to replace code which has nothing in common with question using comments, `pass` or whatever; this would make your problem easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also this is not the answer to your question, and I'm probably getting hundreds of negative points, this is the answer to your not asked question, »how can I wait for many processes stated in parallel?«

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import subprocess

def runprog(name):
    processes = [subprocess.Popen([os.path.abspath(name)], cwd=str(i)) for i in xrange(1,2)]
    for process in processes:
        process.wait()
    print('----------Finaly Done------------')

runprog('cctfiles')
```

Comment: Guys, thank you all!
Especially, I'd like to thank @Daniel! The code @Daniel suggested was exactly what I was trying to do but with kind of more complicated and obviously redundant steps.
Nonetheless, I read all the comments and suggestions and I am really grateful to all of you!

Comment: @Abedin, if this is the answer to your question, you should mark it as the _selected answer_ (the green tick at the left of the question). It'll help people who find this question in the future and will give you some reputation.

Comment: Thanks @BorrajaX,

I didn't know that I had to mark the answer. I clicked the the tick mark left of the Daniel's answer. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: No problem @Abedin. I had to be told on my first question as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

So, when your `try/except` block receives a `BreakIt` exception it doesn't do anything. Because of the `BreakIt` being inside the `while True` loop, it keeps looping. Then you `break` on every exception that is **not** a `BreakIt` one. It sounds like you wanna do the opposite.

You probably want to change your `try/except` to:

```
while True:
    scb('sleep 5', shell = 'True')
    count = 0
    # [ . . . ]
    class BreakIt(Exception): pass
    try:
        for line in fl:
        # [ . . . ]
    except BreakIt:
        break
    else: 
       # Do stuff with not BreakIt exceptions
```

Also: I strongly recommend using the builtin [StopIteration](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.StopIteration) instead of your `BreakIt`. I mean... feel free to create your own exceptions, but in this particular case, you don't need the class, (also, it's a bad practice defining classes within a loop)